# I have two versions of npm installed, and I want to delete one

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-router

I want to delete version 6.0.2.
`npm list react-router-dom`

```
zkzk1123@0.1.0 /Users/123/Desktop/
├─┬ @storybook/addon-links@6.4.8
│ └─┬ @storybook/router@6.4.8
│   └── react-router-dom@6.0.2
└── react-router-dom@5.3.0
```

I tried both `npm uninstall react-router-dom`, `npm uninstall react-router-dom@6.0.2` but @5.3.0 is deleted but @6.0.2 is not, what should I do? I want to delete it.

Comment: delete the req. package, uninstall, delete the npm-package-lock folder as well and then npm install

Comment: You have 2 versions of npm, or 2 versions of a package that was installed with npm?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear. Do you want to delete a version of npm or a version of react-router-dom? To delete a version of react-router-dom, I would suggest you run ‘’’npm uninstall react-router-dom’’’ and then install the required version by running ‘’’npm i react-router-dom@5.3.0’’’

Answer (score 0):

If you are using vscode, you can directly search your folder for the `react-router-dom@5.3.0` you should see it in a package.json file -> delete that line from the dependencies -> delete yarn.lock or npm.lock -> delete node_modules -> run `npm install` or `yarn` if using yarn

Answer (score 0):

It's resolved.
After changing all `@storybook` libraries to @5 version,
 deleting `node_modles and package-lock`, and reinstalling with yarn ,
 `react-router-dom@6` was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. npm uninstall react-router-dom
2. restart npm, finally
3. npm i react-router-dom